# Probability w/ Independent Variables

Tags: probability

Attempting to help son with understanding probability questions. However,it's been a long time since I've had math coures and this one has me a bit confused.  I believe we need to make S= number of vases (out of 20) that have a crack and X= the number of vases in a sample of size $3$ that have a crack. And then solve for probability that $P(S=0\mid X = 0)$.

A potter makes $20$ vases that he rates as being perfect. In review by a patriot $S$ of the vases have fine cracks in the base. With further review $S$ has been determined to range from zero to three. Each equally likely. A customer randomly picks up $3$ different vases which are found to be perfect. What is the probability that $S = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bayes theorem to solve this problem. Each value for S has the same probability ($\frac{1}{4}$) and the probability of getting three perfect vases with S=0 is 1, so there is a 1/4 chance you would have this particular situation (S=0,X=0). For S=2 and S=3, you calculate P(X=0|S={1,2,3}) from the hypergeometric distribution, with total population = 20, target population = S, and n=3. You would calclulate the probability of getting 0 of the target population under each S ={0,1,2,3} multiplied by (1/4) and sum the results. Now, divide (1/3) by this sum to get your conditional probability of there being no cracks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not really sure if i totally got your question. Especially at the end.

I'll give it a try! You have 20 vases, of wich either 0,1,2 or 3 are cracked ("$S=0,1,2,3$"). The probability that $i$ vases ($i=1,2,3$) are cracked is $\frac{1}{4}$ (since they should be equal $\rightarrow\mathbb{P}(S=i)=\frac{1}{4}$).

Now you pick up 3 vases and try to find the probability that non of those 3 is cracked ("$X=0$"). That is $\mathbb{P}(X=0)$. Use the law of the total probability:

$\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\mathbb{P}(X=0|S=0)\mathbb{P}(S=0)+\mathbb{P}(X=0|S=1)\mathbb{P}(S=1)+\mathbb{P}(X=0|S=2)\mathbb{P}(S=2)\mathbb{P}(X=0|S=3)\mathbb{P}(S=3)$

In the case that $S=0$, meaning no vase of the 20 is cracked, the probability that you pick up 3 vases that have no crack is 1 (because there is no bad one!). Hence $\mathbb{P}(X=0|S=0)=1$.

In the case where $S=1$, only one vase of the 20 is cracked. In that case $\mathbb{P}(X=0|S=1)=1-\mathbb{P}(X\neq0|S=0)$. The last terms says that you will pick up the "bad" one. This happens with which probability? (Try on your own first)

Now try to continue on your own!